# Undefined Variable title in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

[image][image]

This error I am getting in Laravel. Can I know what exactly can be the issue. I have spent my full day into this.

Comment: Without seeing some code, we really can't do anything but *guess*. It just means that it hasn't been declared before you're trying to use it.

Comment: Provide the code, please.

Comment: Please don't post images of code in your questions, post the code instead.

Answer (score 2):

you should pass all your variables you use in view, if you use $title as a title for each page in your website you should pass it from your controller function to the view like this:

```
return View::make('home.index')->with('title', 'your title here');
```

and in your view you can make a condition to display public title to all pages don't have a title like this:

```
@if(isset($title)){{$title}} @else {{'Default title here'}} @endif
```

Comment: You can also use `{{ $title or 'Default Title' }}`.

Answer (score 2):

Check your Controller. If in controller variable $title is empty and you manipulate with it then you will get similar error.

Answer (score 1):

your `$title` variable is null .
Make sure that `$title` is not null
try this in your blade

```
@if(isset($title)){{$title}}@endif
```

Comment: Thank for reply. I have added still the problem persists

Comment: no change. still the same